# Google Contacts Api origin_mismatch

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-api, gmail

I used Google ApI v3. I want to get user's contact list .

code is

```
var clientId = 'XXX';
        var apiKey = 'XXX';
        var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly';

        $(document).on("click", ".js-google_contacts", function() {
            gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
            window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 3);
        });

        function checkAuth() {
            gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
        }

        function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        //handler
            }
        }
```

I am working at localhost, I have configured Oauth

```
AUTHORIZED JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS : **http://localhost:80**
AUTHORIZED REDIRECT URI : **http://localhost:80/oauth2callback**
```

but result is

```
400. That’s an error.
Error: origin_mismatch

origin=http://127.0.0.1
redirect_uri=postmessage
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly
response_type=token
immediate=false
include_granted_scopes=true
authuser=0
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: origin "might"(haven't checked myself) be string comparison. so http://localhost:80 might not be equivalent to http://127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Bumped into the same problem. I was playing with different origin URLs, removed and added port, but it appears that it actually takes a while to propagate the setting over google infrastructure.